# 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2095: illegal multibyte sequence, Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, counter

When I install counter package, there's some problems. PLZ somebody help me!! I searched many solutions, but they didn't work for my problem. I think something is wrong with 'Temp' but I'm not sure.

> C:\Users\x3k-k37\Desktop>pip install counter Collecting counter
>   Using cached Counter-1.0.0.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "C:\Users\x3k-k37\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-b488v7dx\counter\setup.py",
>   line 32, in 
>           long_description=getLongDescription(),
>         File "C:\Users\x3k-k37\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-b488v7dx\counter\setup.py",
>   line 13, in getLongDescription
>           for line in file:
>       UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2095: illegal multibyte sequence
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\x3k-k37\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-b488v7dx\counter\

Comment: Probably the `counter` package's description contains some text which isn't representable in your system locale. Try switching to a Unicode locale for the duration of the installation, maybe? (I tried to install the package locally and could not find a `setup.py` or a `long_description` anywhere, but maybe we are looking at different packages.)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. downloaded 'Counter package' from github(https://github.com/KelSolaar/Counter).
>    please refer to Installation in README.rst)
> 2. open 'Counter'in downloaded folder
> 3. edit setup.py below

```
import re
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="Counter",
version="1.0.0",
author="Thomas Mansencal",
author_email="thomas.mansencal@gmail.com",
include_package_data=True,
py_modules=["counter"],
url="https://github.com/KelSolaar/Counter",
license="MIT",
description="Counter package defines the \"counter.Counter\" class similar to bags or multisets in other languages.",
install_requires=[],
tests_require=["nose"],
classifiers=["Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable",
            "Environment :: Console",
            "Intended Audience :: Developers",
            "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
            "Natural Language :: English",
            "Operating System :: OS Independent",
            "Programming Language :: Python",
            "Topic :: Utilities"])
```

> 4. install 'Counter package'

```
python setup.py install
```